# Javascript *and* operator used for a string parameter

Tags: javascript

In *jQuery Mobile* I find the following code:

```
$.jqmData = function( elem, prop, value ){
   return $.data( elem, prop && $.mobile.ns + prop, value );
};
```

What I do not understand is this construct:

```
prop && $.mobile.ns + prop
```

It is using *Javascript's logical and* operator, but for the *key* parameter for the *jQuery data* which is a string parameter. Can someone please explain this construct?

Comment: Where'd you get this piece of code, it looks different (and easier to understand) here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/jquery.mobile.data.js#L92

Comment: It is admittedly an older version of *jQuery Mobile* that is in production at a client site.

Comment: The corresponding version of *jQuery* is *1.6.2*, but this question pertains more to the javascript construct. I am aware that you can use the javascript || operator as a coalesce operator, but have never seen the && operator used in this way before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone please explain this construct?

JavaScript's [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) do not only work on booleans, but on any type. They will internally [convert the values to boolean](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2) to check their truthiness, but they won't change the result type.

For strings, only the empty string is considered falsy. The AND operator `&&` works like "*if the left operand is falsy, return it, otherwise return the right operand*". So if invoked on the string `prop`, it will check whether `prop` is the empty string and then return it, or otherwise concatenate it with `$.mobile.ns`. It's a shortcut for

```
!prop ? prop : $.mobile.ns+prop
// or, if restricted to strings:
prop == "" ? "" : $.mobile.ns+prop
```

Comment: Ah. Ok. This makes sense. I thought that the boolean operators always returned *true* or *false*.

Comment: Thanks, Bergi. The construct makes more sense after this explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript does not implicitly return Boolean values when using Boolean operators:

`&&` returns the second element, if both elements equal to `true` or the first, if one of them is `false`
`||` returns the first element, if it equals to `true`, or the second, if the first matches `false`

Some examples:

```
("foo" && "bar") === "bar"
(1 && "foo") === "foo"
(undefined && false) === undefined
(1 || "foo") === 1
(0 || "foo") === "foo"
(undefined || "foo") === "foo"
(undefined || 1) === 1
(undefined || false) === false
```

Your case from jQuery mobile:

`prop && $.mobile.ns + prop` - in this case `prop` will be used if `prop` AND `$.mobile.ns` are equal to `true`. If one of them is `false`, `$.mobile.ns` will be used. <strike>I think in this situation it's used when `prop === null` which equals an empty string.</strike>

You could expand this to:

```
$.jqmData = function( elem, prop, value ){
   if(prop == false) 
      prop = $.mobile.ns

   return $.data( elem, prop + prop, value );
};
```

Comment: For better understanding one should also note that ``undefined``, ``null``, ``NaN``, ``0``, ``""`` and ``false`` evaluate to ``false`` (falsy values) wheras every other value (like ``{}``, ``[]``, ``"hello"``) evaluates to ``true`` (truthy values).

Comment: Why was this upvoted? "*prop will be used if prop AND $.mobile.ns are equal to true. If one of them is false, $.mobile.ns will be used*", and the expanded code, are plain wrong.

Comment: `(undefined && false) === false` is wrong, too.

Comment: I think that it was upvoted because it was closer to being accurate than the previous answer (which is now deleted) which implied that the expression would return either "true" or "false"

Comment: @BruceHill: Yeah, probably. The first sentence looked very good to me as well, but from there on the quality descends into a complete mess :-(

Comment: Sorry for the low quality of the answer, I had to rush off. Edited it